# Swift Firebase Selected UITableView Prototype Cells - UI Problem

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

There are users being downloaded from firebase and displayed on a UITableView where the cells are selectable and once selected will have a check mark. So from firebase is it is asynchronously downloaded so I think this could be the start of me solving the problem but not sure. When selecting lets say two cells when the view appears and then you begin scrolling through the list other cells will appear to be selected when the user did not select them. Below will be code and pictures of the occurrence.

**Firebase Call**

```
func getTableViewData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let key = snapshot.key
        
        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
                
                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                
                let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)
                
                var singleChildDictionary = locationValue
                singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText as AnyObject
                singleChildDictionary["distanceInMiles"] = distanceInMiles as AnyObject
                self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)
                self.usersArray = self.usersArray.sorted {
                    !($0?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double > $1?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double)
                }
            }
            //insert the rows
            //self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.listedBusiness.reloadData()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

**TableView Setup**

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredUsers.count
    }
    return self.usersArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomerAddSelectedBusinessesCell
    
    var user : NSDictionary?
    
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    
    if cell.isSelected == true {
        
        var user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                print("No access")
                cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
                cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
                cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
                //cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellSelected")
                
                let businessProfilePicture = String(user?["profPicString"] as! String)
                if (businessProfilePicture.count) > 0 {
                    let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture))
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                            cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                            cell.businessImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
                    cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.businessImage.image = image
                }
                
                //cell.profileImage.image =
            //cell.businessDistance.text = String(user?["distanceLabelText"] as! String)
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Access")
                print("****Called")
                cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
                cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
                cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
                cell.businessDistance.text = String(user?["distanceLabelText"] as! String)
                //cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellSelected")
                
                let businessProfilePicture = String(user?["profPicString"] as! String)
                if (businessProfilePicture.count) > 0 {
                    let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture))
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                            cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                            cell.businessImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
                    cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.businessImage.image = image
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
        
    } else if cell.isSelected == false {
        
        var user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                print("No access")
                cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
                cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
                cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
                //cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellNotSelected")
                
                let businessProfilePicture = String(user?["profPicString"] as! String)
                if (businessProfilePicture.count) > 0 {
                    let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture))
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                            cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                            cell.businessImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
                    cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.businessImage.image = image
                }
                
                //cell.profileImage.image =
            //cell.businessDistance.text = String(user?["distanceLabelText"] as! String)
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Access")
                print("%called")
                cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
                cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
                cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
                cell.businessDistance.text = String(user?["distanceLabelText"] as! String)
                //cell.selectedCell.image = UIImage(named: "cellNotSelected")
                
                let businessProfilePicture = String(user?["profPicString"] as! String)
                if (businessProfilePicture.count) > 0 {
                    let url = URL(string: (businessProfilePicture))
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)?.potter_circle
                            cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                            cell.businessImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "default")?.potter_circle
                    cell.businessImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                    cell.businessImage.image = image
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomerAddSelectedBusinessesCell
    
    let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
    let name = user!["uid"] as? String
    var NSdata = NSDictionary()
    var realArray = [NSDictionary]()

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            print("Deleted \(name!)")
            if let idx = data.index(of:name!) {
                data.remove(at: idx)
                print(data)
            }
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            data.append(name!)
            print(data)
        }
    }
    print(data)
}
```

**Selected Cells after view loads**

[image]

**Cells that appear to selected but are not**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's most common cell reusable issue. Cells which are visible to screen will be reused when you scroll.
Eg. You've 5 cells visible. when you select 2,3 and scroll down 7,8 will be selected.
To avoid this you've 2 options.

1. You can use external Bool array to manage this(Bool array count must be same as your array count).
2. You can put bool variable in your user dictionary to manage that.

So whenever your scroll, newly visible cell will not selected automatically.